# Scraping a website with rvest (changing pages, clicking on links)

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am scraping a website with rvest for a research project, and I encounter two problems:

1) My loop seems to be repeating the scraping on the same page over and over again, instead of moving on to the following pages.

2) I can't access the full text WITHIN the links I am scraping. In other words, I would not only like to scrape the search results, but also the content of each of the displayed links. I have the code to do this on each individual page (see below), but as there are 2600 links, I would like to integrate their individual content to the scraping (as if rvest was "clicking" on each of these links and scraping their content).

CONTEXT: French government page. I'm looking for all content with the words "inegalites de sante". This gives approximatively 2600 results, with each page displaying 30 results. Therefore I ran the loop 88 times to collect all results. It is, however, giving me the 30 same results over and over again, and only scraping the small text citation under each result, instead of the full text of each discourse.

See website: http://www.vie-publique.fr/rechercher/recherche.php?replies=30&query=inegalites+de+sante&typeloi=&filter=&skin=cdp&date=1&auteur=&source=&typeDoc=&date=&sort=&filtreAuteurLibre=&dateDebut=&dateFin=&nbResult=2612&q=

```
library(rvest)
library(purrr)

url_base <- "http://www.vie-publique.fr/rechercher/recherche.php?replies=30&query=inegalites+de+sante&typeloi=&filter=&skin=cdp&date=1&auteur=&source=&typeDoc=&date=&sort=&filtreAuteurLibre=&dateDebut=&dateFin=&nbResult=2612&q="

map_df(1:88, function(i) {

  # Progress indicator
  cat(".")

  pg <- read_html(sprintf(url_base, i))

  data.frame(date=html_text(html_nodes(pg, ".date")),
             text=html_text(html_nodes(pg, ".recherche_montrer")),
             title=html_text(html_nodes(pg, ".titre a")),
             stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

}) -> viepublique_data

dplyr::glimpse(viepublique_data)

write.xlsx(viepublique_data, "/Users/Etc.Etc./viepublique_data.xlsx")
```

And here is the code I would use to scrape each individual page to get the full texts, taking the first discourse (no "103000074") as an example:

```
#### Code to scrape each individual page

website <- read_html("http://discours.vie-publique.fr/notices/103000074.html")

section <- website %>% 
  html_nodes(".level1 a") 
section

subsection <- website %>% 
  html_nodes(".level2 p") 
subsection

person <- website %>% 
  html_nodes("p:nth-child(2) , .article p:nth-child(1)") 
person

text <- website %>% 
  html_nodes(".col1 > p") 
text

title <- website %>% 
  html_nodes("h2") 
title
```

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: `sprintf(url_base, 1:88)` returns the same URL 88 times. What were you hoping the `sprintf` would do?

Comment: @MrFlick I thought that it would change the page 88 times (like clicking on "next"), which is obviously not the case here.

Comment: Generally one would think about Selenium if one wnated to "click links".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
require(rvest)
require(tidyverse)
require(stringr)

# The url parameter of interest is the "b" at the end
# it is used for pagination. Just plut in ther 30*(0:87) to get
# the urls of your 88 pages
url_base <- "http://www.vie-publique.fr/rechercher/recherche.php?query=inegalites%20de%20sante&date=&dateDebut=&dateFin=&skin=cdp&replies=30&filter=&typeloi=&auteur=&filtreAuteurLibre=&typeDoc=&source=&sort=&q=&b="
l_out <- 88
urls <- paste0(url_base, seq(0, by = 30, length.out = l_out))
```

Define helper functions to scrape the website:

```
# Helper function for parsing overview
parse_overview <- function(x){
  tibble(date = html_text(html_nodes(x, ".date"), TRUE),
         text_1 = html_text(html_nodes(x, ".recherche_montrer"), TRUE),
         title = html_text(html_nodes(x, ".titre a"), TRUE),
         link = str_trim(html_attr(html_nodes(x, ".titre a"), "href")))
}

# Helper function for collapse multi-line output like person and text
collapse_to_text <- function(x){
  p <- html_text(x, trim = TRUE)
  p <- p[p != ""] # drop empty lines
  paste(p, collapse = "\n")
}

# Parse the result itself
parse_result <- function(x){
  tibble(section = html_text(html_node(x, ".level1 a"), trim = TRUE),
         sub_section = html_text(html_node(x, ".level2 a"), trim = TRUE),
         person = html_nodes(x, "p:nth-child(2) , .article p:nth-child(1)") %>% collapse_to_text,
         text_2 = html_nodes(x, ".col1 > p") %>% collapse_to_text)
}
```

Actual scraping is done as follows:

```
# Scrape overview    
overview_content <- urls %>% 
  map(read_html) %>% 
  map_df(parse_overview)

# scrape all pages - that may take a while... slow website
detail_content <- overview_content$link %>% 
  map(read_html) %>% 
  map_df(parse_result)

out <- bind_cols(overview_content, detail_content)
```

This gives you

```
Variables: 8
$ date        <chr> "11/01/2010", "06/02/2014", "31/03/2011", "30/08/2010", "21/09/2010", "19/05/2010"
$ text_1      <chr> "En effet, l' inégalité d'information n'est pas le moindre déterminant des inégalités de santé",...
$ title       <chr> "1 - Déclaration de Mme Roselyne Bachelot-Narquin, ministre de la santé et des sports, sur la ré...
$ link        <chr> "http://discours.vie-publique.fr/notices/103000074.html", "http://discours.vie-publique.fr/notic...
$ section     <chr> "Discours publics", "Discours publics", "Discours publics", "Discours publics", "Discours public...
$ sub_section <chr> "Les discours dans l'actualité", "Les discours dans l'actualité", "Les discours dans l'actualité...
$ person      <chr> "Personnalité, fonction : BACHELOT-NARQUIN Roselyne.\nFRANCE. Ministre de la santé et des sports...
$ text_2      <chr> "ti : Madame la ministre, chère Fadela,Monsieur le directeur général de la santé, cher Didier Ho...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is really cool. Just one thing: it works perfectly  for the 8 first observations, but I can't get more than that even when (1) replacing "l_out <- 3" by "l_out <- 88", (2) plugging in 30*(0:87) after "b=" in the URL and (3) changing the link (for some reason the one you use gives out 0 results to the word search, but the following works: http://www.vie-publique.fr/rechercher/recherche.php?query=inegalites%20de%20sante&date=&dateDebut=&dateFin=&b=0&skin=cdp&replies=10&filter=&typeloi=&auteur=&filtreAuteurLibre=&typeDoc=&source=&sort=&q=). Would you know why that is?

Comment: Just edited my answer. Please take the code as is. @Evelyne1991 i do not fully understand what you mean by the URL... If you take my `url_base` you see at the very end there is `sort=&q=&b=` so my function itterates over `sort=&q=&b=0`, `sort=&q=&b=30`, `sort=&q=&b=60` and so on. This is called a URL-Parameter and this paginates the pages. So for example the sixed page is ends with `b=150` so: http://www.vie-publique.fr/rechercher/recherche.php?query=inegalites%20de%20sante&date=&dateDebut=&dateFin=&skin=cdp&replies=30&filter=&typeloi=&auteur=&filtreAuteurLibre=&typeDoc=&source=&sort=&q=&b=150

Comment: Thank you so much! It works perfectly. I really appreciate your help with this.